# ksh tab completion not working if I've typed exactly 4 chars before pressing tab

Tags: ksh, autocomplete

If I have the folder ~/1234567 and I type one of the following:

```
ls ~/123
cd ~/12
```

then press tab, everything's groovy.  But if, on either of those commands, I type 1234 before hitting tab, the 4th char is replaced with / and editing text becomes strange; if I hit return it's as if anything after ~ is ignored.  This is repeatable in different locations in the filesystem, and does not depend on which other files/folders are at that location.

This works as expected on bash on the same box. I'm using rhel6.9, and version "93u+ 2012-08-01" of ksh.

I only have this problem if I use ~ and I don't have it if I use the ~username form; just ~/xxxx.

Comment: `ksh --version` should give you the version. Do you have the same issue if you first run `PS1='$ '` and then try the same completion?

Comment: @terdon Thanks, updated question with ksh version. And no change with that prompt.

Comment: This also occurs if the combined length of the username and dir/file is four characters: `cd ~kk/lo<tab>`, and it only occurs in Vi-editing mode it seems.  Thanks for spotting this! I've been wondering _for years_ why this sometimes seems to break. I've tried to submit an issue on the `att/ksh` GitHub, but I'm not sure that's the right place for it...

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this bug exists on other Unices running `ksh93` too.

Looking at how the current development version of the `ksh93` shell handles this, this particular bug *seems* to have been fixed.

The development version [is available from GitHub](https://github.com/att/ast) (on the `master` branch) and the version I tried reports a version string of `Version A 93v-1400-g3d8a9fe4`.

As far as I'm aware, there is no date currently set for the next release, but judging from the frequent commits to the code base, there is development happening.